# is it possible to pass columns through an SSIS script transformation?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a source with 100+ columns.
I need to pass these through a script component transformation, which altersonly a handful of the columns.

Is there a simple way to allow any columns i dont modify to simply pass through the  transformation?

Currently, i have to pass them all in, and assign them to the output with no changes. 
This is a lot of work for 100 columns and id rather not have to do it if possible!

FYI:
There is no unique key, so i cannot split out the records using multicast and merge them after the script component.

Comment: Are you using an Asynchronous Script transformation or the default, Synchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have to choose what columns you want included in your script component as either read only  or read/write.

Anything you do not select as read/write simply passes through.

There are things you can do with a script task. Like add an output column to your current data flow or even create a separate data flow output.

In your case. you will want to select the handful of columns that you want to alter as read/write, then modify those columns in script and the rest will just pass through.

Comment: Unless im missing something,  i still have to assign all the columns to the output, otherwise there is no output from the transform

Comment: Look at the "Input Columns" screen on GUI, that's were you select what columns you want to work with. Anything not selected or selected as read only are passed through without alteration.

Comment: "Inputs and Outputs" allows you to add columns to your data flow or to create a whole new Output flow.

Comment: That helped, I didint realize that when using the component in synchronous mode, I dont have to assign values to the output, I can simply update the value in any read/write columns directly in the Row currently being processed. Thanks for the expertise and advise!